# Distributing 14 baseball cards in one week

Tags: probability

I am going over the Counting Rule, which is an extremely basic rule in probability.

Why, then, does applying it to this question seem so counterintuitive?

"Virginia wants to give her son, Brian, 14 different baseball cards within a 7-day period.  If Virginia gives Brian cards no more than once a day, in how many way can this be done?"

Standing back and looking at this, I see 3 different numbers -- we have 14 baseball cards, we have 7 days, and "one per day". So we are looking to count combinations, using the Counting Rule. We are counting different sequences we can distribute baseball cards. I see the answer is $ 7^{14}$ but honestly don't get this at all.

In my mind, I can envision distributing baseball cards across days. But I can't conceptualize what it means to take the days to the power of the cards.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how Virginia is distributing the cards. Can she give Brian as many cards as she likes on a given day?

Comment: @DougM: assuming that Virginia can distribute as many cards as she likes on a given day, $7^{14}$ is the correct answer: for each of the $14$ cards there are $7$ possible days to give it to Brian.

Comment: This is how I read the puzzle: Virginia has 14 different baseball cards that she's going to give her son, Brian. She has 7 envelopes that she'll split the cards amongst, giving him one envelope every day for a week. (Can some of the envelopes be empty?). Clearly here the cards within one envelope don't have an order; they are given at the same time. But the envelopes have an order - the days of the week.

Comment: @carmichael561 I misread the question, and have deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: @carmichael561: Why did you read this as "for each of the $7$ days, there are $14$ possible cards to give to Brian." I know you typed out the answer, but how did your mind visualize it? To me, I just read the sentence you wrote, but it has no meaning. It may as well be "Each days of Brian $7$ for the...". What is the underlying thought process?

Comment: It might be easier to think of it with say $2$ cards rather than $14$. Virginia has the option of giving card $1$ to Brian on any of the $7$ days of the week, leading to $7$ choices. She has the same $7$ choices for card $2$ independently of the choice she made for the first card, hence (in the case of only $2$ cards) she has $7^2$ choices in total. The same logic works for any number of cards.

Comment: now it sounds so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessarily "one per day". 
Think of the problem in the way: Each of the baseball cards have 7 ways to be given.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as finding the number of solutions to the equation $$x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_7=14$$ where $x_i$ is the number of cards given on the $i$ th day and the $x_i$ are non-negative.
Using stars and bars we find that there are $$\binom{14+7-1}{14}=\binom{20}{14}\,\, \text{ways.}$$

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but I imagine that the cards are distinguishable.

Comment: It's a terribly worded question. From Saeed Ghahramani's 3rd edition "Fundamentals of Probability" in case anyone cares.

Comment: It is made explicit in the question that the cards are different.